# write a function to calculate CAGR in r

Tags: r, function

I have a dataset that contains a number of features, among are Area, Rainfall and Yield, in addition to the Year column. I want to write a feature that calculates the Compound Annual Growth Rate for each of (Area, Rainfall and Yield). I have the following function but I need to adapt it in a way that can take any of these columns to calculate its CAGR:

```
annual.growth.rate <- function(data){
  
  T1 <- max(data$Year) - min(data$Year)+1
  FV <- data[which(data$Year == max(data$Year)),"Area"]
  SV <- data[which(data$Year == min(data$Year)),"Area"]
  cagr <- ((FV/SV)^(1/T1)) -1
  
}
```

There is something not right in the function I need to adjust it.

Sample from the data:

```
X                       State Year      Season                Crop  Area Production
1 0 Andaman and Nicobar Islands 2000 Kharif                 Arecanut  1254       2000
2 1 Andaman and Nicobar Islands 2000 Kharif      Other Kharif pulses     2          1
3 2 Andaman and Nicobar Islands 2000 Kharif                     Rice   102        321
4 3 Andaman and Nicobar Islands 2000 Whole Year               Banana   176        641
5 4 Andaman and Nicobar Islands 2000 Whole Year            Cashewnut   720        165
6 5 Andaman and Nicobar Islands 2000 Whole Year             Coconut  18168   65100000
  Rainfall        Yield
1   2763.2    1.5948963
2   2763.2    0.5000000
3   2763.2    3.1470588
4   2763.2    3.6420455
5   2763.2    0.2291667
6   2763.2 3583.2232497
```

Comment: Can you explain what is not right? The results or do you receive any errors? And, maybe share your data. You can run `dput(head(data))` and copy the output as code to your question.

Comment: I am no getting output, I think the mistake is in the arguments and how to make it more general to except any column and not to make it specific to Area.

Comment: First, do you have mistake in `SV <- data[which(data$Month ==`? Shouldn't you have `data$Year`

Comment: Yes it is a mistake but I it has been corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. Maybe you are missing `print(cagr)`in your function:

```
annual.growth.rate <- function(data){
  T1 <- max(data$Year) - min(data$Year)+1
  FV <- data[which(data$Year == max(data$Year)),"Area"]
  SV <- data[which(data$Year == min(data$Year)),"Area"]
  cagr <- ((FV/SV)^(1/T1)) -1
  print(cagr)
}
```

If you want to do it for multiple variables, you can make a for loop inside the function:

```
annual.growth.rate <- function(data){
  for (i in c("Area", "Rainfall", "Yield")) {
  T1 <- max(data$Year) - min(data$Year)+1
  FV <- data[which(data$Year == max(data$Year)),i]
  SV <- data[which(data$Year == min(data$Year)),i]
  cagr <- ((FV/SV)^(1/T1)) -1
  print(cagr)}
}
```

Comment: Ok, that is one thing, thank you. But I go negative values, do you know why? Also what should I write instead of "Area" in the Which condition to make it accept other passed columns such as Rainfall and Yield?

Comment: The annual growth rate could also be negative. If the real values were lower at the end of the period, the growth would be negative.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. I will appreciate it if you could answer the other part of the question..

Comment: I updated my answer. Is this what you are asking for?

Comment: Yes, that is. Thank you. I accepted your answer. One more thing, how can I add columns of output cagr to the dataset?